# Spark Data Frame Writer - Range Partiotioning

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to have Spark Data Frame Writer write based on RangePartioning?

For Ex -

I have 10 distinct values for column_a, say 1 to 10.

```
df.write
.partitionBy("column_a")
```

Above code by default will create 10 folders .. column_a=1,column_a=2 ...column_a=10

I want to see if it is possible to have these partitions based on bucket - col_a=1to5,  col_a=5-10 .. or something like that? Then also have query engine respect it

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to write your own Partitioner to do that. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137693/translating-scala-code-to-java-for-spark-partitioner

Comment: ya but that would only partition data in RDD. Would it also partition the data when it is written to files at disk? (diving data in folders)

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. Use `MultipleOutputFormat` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438615/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-output-files-for-a-map-reduce